# Deserialize in-string JSON using Gson

Tags: android, gson

I am using Retrofit 2 with `GsonConverter`. The problem is I have this response:

```
"responseData": {
   "data": "<json array>"
}
```

As you can see one of the parameters is a JSON array, but it is a string. Should I use `TypeAdapter` and override the `read` and `write` methods? If so can you show how I can do this?

Comment: You might find the following question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42494438/storing-arbitrary-data-with-gson-and-hibernate

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see one of the parameters is a JSON array, but it is a string.

If the response generator is under your control, you should definitely change the response format (both for well-formedness and performance (Gson does not allow to read/write string literals as raw values)).

> Should I use `TypeAdapter` and override the `read` and `write` methods?

If you cannot control your server response, you have to implement a custom type adapter with the `read` method implemented only. To align with that response format, you could define custom mappings like these:

```
final class Response<T> {

    final ResponseData<T> responseData = null;

}
```

```
final class ResponseData<T> {

    // This is where we're telling Gson to apply the special read strategy, not to all types
    @JsonAdapter(RawJsonTypeAdapterFactory.class)
    final T data = null;

}
```

As you can see, you just have to bind a custom type adapter to a specific field only. Despite the `JsonAdapter` annotation accepts `TypeAdapter` classes as well, you cannot bind `TypeAdapter` directly because you need `Gson` and `Type` instances.

```java
final class RawJsonTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    // Gson will instantiate it itself without any issues   
    private RawJsonTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        // No additional checks here, we're assuming the necessary fields are properly annotated
        final Type type = typeToken.getType();
        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override
            public T read(final JsonReader in)
                    throws IOException {
                return gson.fromJson(in.nextString(), type);
            }
        }.nullSafe(); // And making the type adapter null-safe
    }

}
```

Now JSON documents like

```
{
    "responseData": {
        "data": "[1,2,3]"
    }
}
```

can be easily parsed in plain Java:

```java
private static final Type intArrayResponseType = new TypeToken<Response<int[]>>() {
}.getType();

private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

...

try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = getPackageResourceJsonReader(Q43456942.class, "stringified.json") ) {
    final Response<int[]> response = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, intArrayResponseType);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(response.responseData.data));
}
```

Output:

> [1, 2, 3]

Your Retrofit-bound service might have a method declared this (no type tokens necessary since Retrofit is smart enough to pass the `Call` parameterization to the underlying Gson converter):

```java
Call<Response<int[]>> getIntArray();
```